# Input decimal with commas in c#

Tags: c#, string, culture

i have a question

in Indonesia, we usually use 8,5 not 8.5
but when i write 8,5 in textbox it mean 85

how to solve it?
simply i want to change the dot with commas

Comment: @user can u tell me how to do that sir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using `double.TryParse` somewhere. Switch to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) and pass in an Indonesian culture for the `provider` parameter using `new CultureInfo("id-ID")`.

Example with `double.Parse`:

```
double result = double.Parse("6,5", new CultureInfo("id-ID"));
```